# How to implement 5V NPN component to a 3.3V MCU input pin

Tags: microcontroller, interface, electrical

I just want to make sure about how to implement this
[image]

to an MCU's input pin, if the MCU is limited to 8mA sinking/source current. And 3.3V input voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply is 4.55~24V, while output is Open collector to any low voltage, so you can pullup to 3.3V limited to 13mA.  This does not use MCU current but rather Vdc only.

Thus you could  choose 1K (3.3mA) or 10K (0.33mA) which is adequate.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure no MCU current is drawn.